# Page specific javascripts in Play

Tags: javascript, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm building a small application in Play and have an 'outer' template which holds all my CSS and JS imports (jQuery and my main.js file). CSS at the top, JS at the bottom with a body tag in between... pretty basic stuff:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/foundation.css")">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">

        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.at("images/favicon.png")">
    </head>

    <body>
        @content
    </body>

    <script src='@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src='@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/index.js")' type="text/javascript"> </script>
</html>
```

Which is fine.

However, I  have page specific javascript functions that should run based on what the page is. So if I go to localhost:9000/test, I want a particular set of functions to run.
If I go to localhost:9000/chips, I want another set of functions to run.

I can't see a neat way of doing this, really, except checking the current page url in the script and executing functions based on that... but the routes file is already doing stuff based on the current page url - seems strange to have to do something so similar twice.

One solution is to put all my scripts at the top and then execute inline scripts in the HTML... but I hate doing things like that.

Answer (score 4):

You have very nice and clear sample available in the... [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaTemplateUseCases).

Scroll to the bottom and check section: **moreScripts and moreStyles equivalents**, you have there ready to use samples.

Answer (score 1):

I use a ViewModel approach to solve this issue.

**The default ViewModel:**

```
class DefaultPage(
  implicit val request: RequestHeader,
  implicit val lang: Lang) {

  var title: String = null
  val styles = mutable.LinkedHashMap.empty[String, Int]
  val scripts = mutable.LinkedHashMap.empty[String, Int]

  def title(title: String) {
    this.title = title
  }

  def style(style: String)(implicit priority: Int = 500) {
    styles.put(style, priority)
  }

  def script(script: String)(implicit priority: Int = 500) {
    scripts.put(script.toString, priority)
  }

  def translate(message: String, objects: Any*) = Messages(message, objects: _*)
}
```

Then I have two template tags:

**styles.scala.html**

```
@(styles: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Int])

@for(style <- styles.toList.sortBy(_._2)) {
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="@routes.Assets.at(style._1)" />
}
```

**scripts.scala.html**

```
@(scripts: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Int])

@for(script <- scripts.toList.sortBy(_._2)) {
  <script async="true" src="@routes.Assets.at(script._1)"></script>
}
```

My main template:

**main.scala.html**

```
@(page: util.view.models.DefaultPage)(content: Html)

@import tags.scripts
@import tags.styles

@page.style("css/vendor/normalize.min.css")(1)
@page.style("css/vendor/formalize.min.css")(1)
@page.style("css/sprites.min.css")(1)
@page.style("css/main.min.css")(1)
@page.style("css/quirks.min.css")(1000)
@page.script("js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")(1)
@page.script("js/vendor/jquery.formalize.min.js")(1)
@page.script("js/plugins.min.js")(1)
@page.script("js/main.min.js")(1)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@page.title</title>
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

        @styles(page.styles)
        <script src="@routes.Assets.at("js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js")"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="@page.lang.code @page.lang.language @page.lang.country">
        @content
        @scripts(page.scripts)
    </body>
```

And a sub template:

```
@(page: util.view.models.ContactUsPage)

@page.title(page.translate("contact.us.title"))
@page.style("css/contact-us.min.css")
@page.script("js/vendor/jquery.expandable-1.1.4.js")
@page.script("js/contact-us.min.js")
@main(page) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your javascript which is specific to a page as template parameter [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826906/how-to-pass-a-script-to-main-scala-html-play-2?rq=1)